# Fedora 29 infinite system check on boot

Tags: linux, boot, fedora

I cannot boot into fedora. Boot is stucked on:

**A start job is running for File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/...**

I let it be for about 4 hours but nothing happened.
But with flag **fastboot** it boots normally. 
The uuid of disk is correct in fstab file.

Any ideas ?

SOLVED there [How to delete folder from EFI partition - Microsoft](https://superuser.com/questions/1425600/how-to-delete-folder-from-efi-partition-microsoft)

Answer (score 1):

#### Background

Booting can be a variable process.  It's not just loading critical parts of the operating system into memory.  There can also be a lot of checking to identify hardware, load appropriate drivers, and test various parts of the system to make sure they're working and figure out what settings to use.

Until recently, a normal boot of an installed system shaved off a little time compared to booting a live session by figuring out a lot of the settings and driver requirements during the installation.  It can just verify that the system looks the same.  The fastboot that Fedora started implementing with v29 takes that a step farther by eliminating more of the time-intensive checks.  You can read more about that [here](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Fedora-30-Defaulting-Fastboot) and [here](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Intel-Fastboot-Default-2019-Try).

One of the common checks during boot is the integrity of the system drive.  There are several things that can happen to a drive.  For example, if you power down unexpectedly or interrupt activity when information is being written to the drive, the information can be left corrupted.  More serious is when the drive starts to physically fail and portions of the drive are no longer able to properly record or retain information.

In some cases, the system knows that something happened that left the potential for corruption.  During boot, one of the things it checks is the indicator for that condition.  If things might be corrupted, it adds a quick check of the drive.  Because there can be corruption that the system isn't aware of, there may be periodic checks; every so often, the boot will be a little longer to do a spot check.  Some distros may do a quick check on every boot.  It appears that Fedora's fastboot at least reduces the frequency of prophylactic drive checks during boot.

#### Your experience

What might be happening in your case is that when you enable fast boot, it skips checking the drive and boots quickly.  When you disable fastboot, it checks the drive and finds problems.

If you have a large drive with a lot of corruption, the checking and repair process can take many hours.  Every corrupted area it comes to, it tries over and over to read what's there in an effort to recover it and move it to a good area of the drive.  If it spent four hours doing that (and it sounds like it may not have finished), your drive had serious problems.  It's possible that they were all soft errors and four hours was long enough to clean up a lot of it.  It's also possible that it was all or mostly in areas that didn't affect your day-to-day usage so you weren't aware of any problems.

#### What to do

The wise course of action is to:

1. Check the SMART stats on the drive.  If the drive is failing, that's where you'll see it.
2. As soon as possible, do your own [file system check](https://www.linode.com/docs/quick-answers/linux/how-to-use-fsck-to-fix-disk-problems/). Assume that it could take many hours; maybe allocate half a day to ensure that it can run uninterrupted to completion.
3. For the subsequent several months, retest it maybe every few days initially, and then once a week or so.  After step 2, retests shouldn't take nearly as long.

If it finds a lot of soft errors in step 2, that alone doesn't mean that the drive is failing.  If you clean it up and it stays cleaned up, or new corruption happens after known human or environmental problems, that's probably not the drive's fault.  The warning sign is if you clean it up, and every time you retest it, it finds some new corruption.  Even worse is if that is in increasing amounts.  If you see that, minimize your reliance on the drive and replace it as soon as possible.

Comment: Thank you very much for reply. I have M.2 Intel SSD.I followed the turorial you posted. I tried **fsck** with parametr -A from Fedora Live CD, but nothing happened. It only shows: **fsck from util-linux2.32.1.** I checked syntax several times. I'm was trying it many hours yesterday.

Comment: @vone, it's hard to do this interactively over a Q&A site.  You need to identify how the problem device is identified when you boot the live session (its sd letter).  If you specified the wrong device, it may have had nothing to check.  It needs to be unmounted.  -A checks all disks listed in /etc/fstab, or all filesystems (partitions) on the drive you specify.  My recollection is that -A only checks and reports.  -y checks and does an interactive repair, but you need  a little knowledge to make choices.  (cont'd)

Comment: -a will check and try an automated repair.  It may take awhile to run, but you should get some feedback and it should eventually return you to a prompt.  If you didn't get back to a prompt, it was still running.

Comment: One other thought.  Try prefixing the fsck command with sudo.  You may be having a permissions issue.  When it asks for your password, try your admin (root) password for the problem drive.  If that doesn't work, try the root password for the live session (if you can't find a reference for it and it wasn't displayed at startup, the password is often either "root" or "toor").

Comment: Thank you very much for your patience. fsck returned no errors.

Comment: I will try to let it do the system check on start up for a day. Then I'll post the result.

Comment: So, I figured out that it is problem with boot (efi) partition - specifically with Microsoft folder (I have dual boot but trying to solve this problem I broke Windows :) ). I tried to delete it from live CD (partition mounted with rw permissions) but it says: Read only file system. I also tried grub2-mkconfig and there are infinite input output errors. See the picture [here](https://pasteboard.co/I9P9My8.png)