# How to delete folder from EFI partition - Microsoft

Tags: linux, windows, boot, fedora

I have problem with my Fedora disto. Boot is stucked on system check on disk by UUID...
I discovered that it is EFI partition and I tried to reconfigure grub2 but there are inffinite Input Outpur errors(see [here](https://pasteboard.co/IaeKpkE.png)) in Microsoft folder (yes, I have dual boot but each system on different disk). During my investigation I completely broke Windows so I want to delete Microsoft folder - fix Fedora and reinstall Windows. BUT when I try to delete the folder (sudo rm -rf... - also from Live CD with partition booted with RW permissions) it says that it is Read Only file system.
What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: If you delete the EFI partition you will make Windows unbootable

Comment: Is any of the Windows or Fedora in bootable state?

Comment: Yes, when I added fastboot parametr to kernel in grub2 Fedora is bootable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "read-only filesystem" error might be caused by the OS detecting the filesystem (FAT32) on the EFI partition is corrupted.

If you can, copy the contents of the Fedora folder out of the EFI partition to some temporary safe place. Then, you can try running `/sbin/fsck.fat` on it, or if that won't solve the problem, use the nuclear option (i.e. a complete reformat and rebuild of the EFI partition):

1.) Identify the current volume ID of the EFI partition using `blkid`. It will be reported as `UUID=` for that partition.

2.) Unmount and then reformat the entire EFI partition using `mkfs.vfat -i <volume-ID> -F 32 /dev/<your EFI partition>`. When specifying the volume-ID, you'll need to omit the dash: specify the hexadecimal numbers only.

For example, if `blkid` reported the volume ID as `UUID="3610-E638"`, the mkfs command should be `mkfs.vfat -i 3610e638 -F 32 ...`

3.) Mount the EFI partition again, then restore the Fedora folder back into place. Or if it was impossible to copy the existing Fedora folder because of the corruption, you could use `grub-install` (or `grub2-install` in some Linux distributions) to completely reinstall the GRUB bootloader from scratch.

You may also need to regenerate the GRUB configuration file using `grub-mkconfig` (`grub2-mkconfig` in some Linux distributions). See your Linux distribution's documentation to find the location of the GRUB configuration file, and use the -o option to direct the new configuration file to the correct location. Example: `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg`.

Since the GRUB configuration is automatically regenerated by `grub-mkconfig` on each kernel update anyway, the new configuration should be identical to the old one unless you've customized the GRUB configuration manually... and in that case you should know what you did.

If your EFI partition is mounted in `/boot/efi` and the GRUB configuration file is not within that filesystem (e.g. in `/boot/grub2/grub.cfg`), then using `grub-mkconfig` is probably unnecessary. However, running it anyway should not be harmful.

4.) Use the `efibootmgr -v` command to view the firmware NVRAM boot settings and verify that they are still correct and that Fedora's bootloader path name is correct relative to the root of the EFI partition.

Comment: Thank you very much for reply. When I try to copy the folder it shows: Input/output error. Am I out of luck ?

Comment: Well, that indicates the EFI partition is definitely corrupted. Reinstalling the bootloader from scratch is not too difficult either: instead of restoring the Fedora folder to the recreated EFI filesystem, just use `grub-install` (or `grub2-install` in some Linux distributions) to reinstall the bootloader.

Comment: Ok, blkid returned UUID="3610-E638" but when I try run command you posted with this UUID it shows: Volume ID must be a hexadecimal number. Sorry for another question. I'm using mkfs for first time.

Comment: As I said, leave out the dash: type just `mkfs.vfat -i 3610e638 -F 32` and the partition device name.

Comment: Oh I fool, thank you. It finished with no errors. I done grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg. Now I will try to reboot and reply I it worked.

Comment: It works ! Thank you so much ! I've been trying to solve this for three weeks !

Comment: I've used your comments to clarify the answer, as the comments will not be permanent. Hopefully it will now be more clear if anyone else has the same problem...